# Why is my background shown under the footer in Qualtrics?

Tags: html, css, qualtrics

I have no idea why my background is shown under the footer in Qualtrics.

Here is the code I have written:

```
<br />
<style type="text/css">body {
  background-image:url('https://uwmadison.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_00pfOKSXTudGqfb') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size:50% 50% !important;
  background-position:center center !important;
    height:100vh !important;
}
</style>
```

So here's a screenshot of how it is shown:
[image]
And here's the [link](https://uwmadison.qualtrics.com/SE/?SID=SV_exkWSVu4vGr6tnL) to the survey (I put 6 minutes as the timer for the first photo so you can see it)

Comment: To clarify, which part is considered the footer? The inspect element isn't showing anything inside of the footer. It also looks as if you do not have any height declared on your "footer" id.

Comment: Would changing the class from `body` to `div#SkinContent` be an option? Or must the background be for the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

Backgrounds are positioned based on the window (viewport).

If you want that image to be above the footer, include it in your html above the footer with `<img />`

You also might be interested in fixing the footer to the bottom of the page.

Comment: I actually tried that but if I use <img/ > it is not considered background anymore. Right?

Comment: Right, alternatively you could assign the background to a div above the footer instead of the body. But this might require setting width/height or min-height/min-width.
```<div style="background: url(img); width:100%; height: 300px">
</div>
```